# ESB mule : differences in notation

Tags: mule

imagine a very simple flow with a HTTP inbound and a body-to-parameter-map. Payload contains something like `{prop1=aaa, prop2=eee, prop3=iii}`.

My question is, why if I try to access `#[payload.prop1]` sometimes (and I said sometimes) it gets null value, while `#[payload['prop1']]` seems to be allways correct?

Comment: which Mule ESB version?

Comment: I think is the latest one (Anypoint Studio July 2014 Release)

Answer (score 0):

Those are equivalent, the only different would be that the dot notation also support objects while the key one only support collections.

It's perhaps that the you are using the dot notation with keys that already contain a dot? Like http.status. In those cases you should either escape with 'http.status'.